# Function '<procedurename>' doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you m,ssing a 'Return' statement?

Tags: vb.net

Consider :

```
Private Function isAvailableQuantity() As Boolean
    Try
        sqL = "SELECT StocksOnHand FROM ITEM WHERE ItemNo = " & Val(txtSearch.Text) & ""
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)


        If dr.Read = True Then

            If Val(txtQuantity.Text) <= dr(0) Then
                isAvailableQuantity = True
            Else
                MsgBox("Insuficient stocks", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Validate Stocks")
                txtSearch.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)


    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

I don't know what to do. The older version visual studio doesn't get this error.
i am using vs 2022 right now and it seems to have an error on the contrary vs 2010 doesn't

Comment: Firstly, please don't submit your question if your code formatting is a mess. This site provides a preview for a reason and you can see whether your question looks as it should. If it doesn't, fix it before posting.

Comment: As for the issue, did you put any thought into it? The fact that all you've done is post an error message and some code suggests that you haven't. The error message tells you that the method doesn't return a value on all paths. Did you make the effort to trace all possible paths through your code and see whether a value was returned on each one? It would appear not. Given that the only place you actually return a value is inside two `If` blocks, there's plenty of scope for a value to not be returned.

Comment: sorry but out teacher didn't discuss this properly he just sent as a video file of him doing it and expects us to solve every problem that he places

Comment: Put some thought into it. There are numerous paths that execution could take through that code. You need to ensure that a value is returned on all of them. What do you actually want to happen? If you don't know that then why are you even writing code? Presumably you want to return `False` in all but the specific case that you are currently returning `True`, so actually do that. Apply some logic BEFORE you write the code. If you want the result to be `False` in all but one specific situation, why not set the result to `False` by default and then only change it to `True` in that situation?

Comment: actually i dont even know what return do

Comment: It's not great if you have a bad teacher but it's not for sites like this to teach you the basics. There are plenty of beginner tutorials out there so, if your teacher is doing it for you, you need to go out and do it for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET, a `Function` is a method that returns a value and a `Sub` is a method that doesn't return a value. If your method doesn't need to return anything, use a `Sub`, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub DoSomething()
    'Do some stuff here.
End Sub
```

If you do use a `Function` then there are two ways to return a value. The bad way is to assign a value to the implicit local variable that is named after the method, e.g.

```vb
Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
    'Do some stuff here.

    DoSomething = True
End Function
```

That way basically only exists to support upgraded VB6 code. If your teacher is showing you that then they are obviously an old VB6 developer who hasn't actually learned VB.NET properly. The good way to return a value is with an explicit `Return` statement, e.g.

```vb
Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
    'Do some stuff here.

    Return True
End Function
```

If there are multiple paths that execution could take through your code, you need to make sure that a value is returned on all of them. As an example, this code does not do that:

```vb
Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
    If Date.Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

That will return `True` on Mondays but it doesn't return anything on other days. In this specific case, one fix would be this:

```vb
Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
    If Date.Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

If you are going to use the bad way to return a value and you want to return a particular value on all but one code path then the logical thing to do is to set the return value at the start to the default and then only change it in that one place, e.g.

```vb
Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
    DoSomething = False

    If Date.Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
        DoSomething = True
    End If
End Function
```

That last example is the easiest (although not best) fix for your scenario.